# OnClick Listener Fails to Load Layout

Tags: android, xml

I've created a java file which should allow a user to click on the image and load another layout (super simple bit of code - but keep in mind I'm a bit of a noob) but every time I click it I get a force close error message although everything seems correct to me (which show's what I know)

I know this is probably something super simple - or an off by one type issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

JAVA

```
package com.example.linkingmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View; import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);
}
public class Test extends Activity {  

 public void imageClick(View view) {  
  //Implement image click function
     Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this, AppActivity.class);
     App2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
 }  
    }
;
}
```

---

LOGCAT

```
03-06 16:55:06.709: E/Trace(1634): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-06 16:55:07.279: D/dalvikvm(1634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 8% free 2456K/2652K, paused 47ms, total 50ms
03-06 16:55:07.319: I/dalvikvm-heap(1634): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.831MB for 3456016-byte allocation
03-06 16:55:07.479: D/dalvikvm(1634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 5829K/6028K, paused 152ms, total 152ms
03-06 16:55:07.579: D/dalvikvm(1634): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5828K/6028K, paused 10ms+16ms, total 100ms
03-06 16:55:08.209: D/libEGL(1634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-06 16:55:08.209: D/(1634): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1727a0, tid 1634
03-06 16:55:08.289: D/libEGL(1634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-06 16:55:08.299: D/libEGL(1634): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-06 16:55:08.499: W/EGL_emulation(1634): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-06 16:55:08.569: D/OpenGLRenderer(1634): Enabling debug mode 0
03-06 16:55:11.969: W/EGL_emulation(1634): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-06 16:55:18.629: D/AndroidRuntime(1634): Shutting down VM
03-06 16:55:18.629: W/dalvikvm(1634): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method imageClick(View) in the activity class com.example.linkingmanager.App2Activity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'imageView1'
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: imageClick [class android.view.View]
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
03-06 16:55:18.659: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `onClick` property inside your layout file (`R.layout.main2`):

```
android:onClick="imageClick"
```

This layout is part of `App2Activity` view hierarchy . So you have to declare the `imageClick(View)` method inside `App2Activity`:

```
public class App2Activity extends Activity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    }

     public void imageClick(View view) {  
         Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this, AppActivity.class);
         App2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
     }  

}
```

and not inside the `Test` class.

Comment: How is this different from the previous answer (that Amani Swann already stated was the solution)?

Comment: @Sam, this is very different. This explains the reason why your code does not work. The other answer just gives you a brand new solution - without telling you where you went wrong.

Comment: @Phil I see, TGMCains changed his answer (with a "ninja edit"). So yes it is different now. I agree code-only answers are less than ideal, but so are duplicates. However this is neither (and properly formatted).

Answer (score 1):

Why you define another activity inside another.

```
public class App2Activity extends Activity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this, AppActivity.class);
            App2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I was combining code... I apologize for making such a simple mistake.


Removing it resolved the issue. 

Thank you!!